# Azure AD B2C Property identifierUris is invalid

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am attempting to migrate my legacy db to my Azure B2C tenet using the instructions seen [here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/user-migration/tree/master/seamless-account-migration).

Step 2 has me make the following call in powershell:

```
$url = "https://graph.windows.net/$tenant/applications/$AppObjectID/extensionProperties?api-version=1.6"

#Define the extension attribute
$body = @"
{ 
 "name": "requiresMigration", 
 "dataType": "Boolean", 
 "targetObjects": ["User"]
}
"@

#Generate the authentication header and make the request
$authHeader = @{"Authorization"= $oauth.access_token;"Content-Type"="application/json";"ContentLength"=$body.length }
$result = Invoke-WebRequest -Headers $authHeader -Uri $url -Method Post -Body $body
```

When I attempt to register the "requiresMigration" attribute, I get the following powershell error:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"odata.error":{"code":"Request_BadRequest","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Property identifierUris is inval
id."},"requestId":"3ba925e7-7ddc-4bdd-8922-4e01e8f31e99","date":"2020-04-10T00:16:52","values":[{"item":"PropertyName","value":"
identifierUris"},{"item":"PropertyErrorCode","value":"GenericError"}]}}
```

The actual AD logs show:

```
Activity Status
Status : Failure
Reason : Microsoft.Online.Workflows.ValidationException
```

Could someone help me find actionable information on this error?

Comment: What is the value of `identifierUris` in the manifest.xml file of your Azure AD app? Please check it. It is not required. So if there is anything here, remove it and keep it as `"identifierUris": [],` then have a retry with the Powershell script.

Comment: Hi @DMop, do you have any updates about `identifierUris`?